# Optimization Of Sum of Coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the maximum sum of the coefficients of a monic quartic polynomial whose roots are all greater than 1 and multiply to 2145?

I've tried writing out the polynomial, which we know is of the form x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+2145. I know that you have to try and use Vieta, so I have written out all the equations in terms of the roots, but nothings coming of it. I keep running about in circles.

Comment: How do you know the degree is $4$?

Comment: In this case, less is more. Increasing the degree of the polynomial would 'split' 2145 into unnecessarily many factors, which would in turn sum to a smaller number. So think simple. Just looking at the factors of 2145 should give you an idea of what the biggest sum would be. (Spoiler: it's 718)

Comment: @ChubbyChef are you assuming the roots/coefficients are all integers? No such restriction is given in the problem statement. I can get a sum exceeding $1135$. Even sticking to integers, I can get a sum exceeding $950$. And we can beat that by going to degree two.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did assume integers only, yes. Maybe the assumption was wrong, so I only left it as a comment. I got the impression from the algebra-precalculus tag.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant a quartic polynomial only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(X)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ such that all roots of $f$ are real and $>1$, and $f(0)=(-1)^n\cdot 2145$. We want to maximize $f(1)$.
In particular, for odd $n$, we find that $f(1)<0$. Hence we need only consider the case of even $n$.

Let the roots of $f$ be $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in[1,2145]$. Then $f(1)$ is a continuous function $$\phi(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)=\prod_k(\alpha_k-1) $$of the $\alpha_k$, and as the set
$$\{\,(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\in[1,2145]^n\mid \prod\alpha_k=2145\,\} $$
is compact, the (clearly positive) maximum of $\phi$ is actually achieved in some point.
Let $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ be a maximizer. Then clearly $\alpha_k>1$ for all $k$.
Pick two indieces $1\le i<j\le n$ and
let
$$\beta_k=\begin{cases}\sqrt{\alpha_i,\alpha_j}&k\in\{i,j\}\\\alpha_k&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Then
$$1\ge \frac{\phi(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)}{\phi(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)}=\frac{(\beta_i-1)(\beta_j-1)}{(\alpha_i-1)(\alpha_j-1)}=\frac{\beta_i\beta_j-(\beta_i+\beta_j)+1}{(\alpha_i-1)(\alpha_j-1)}=\frac{\alpha_i\alpha_j-(\beta_i+\beta_j)+1}{(\alpha_i-1)(\alpha_j-1)}.$$
By the AM-GM inequality,
$$\alpha_i+\alpha_j\ge 2\sqrt{\alpha_i\alpha_j}=\beta_i+\beta_j $$
with equality iff $\alpha_i=\alpha_j=\sqrt{\alpha_i\alpha_j}$.
Hence,
$$ \frac{\alpha_i\alpha_j-(\beta_i+\beta_j)+1}{(\alpha_i-1)(\alpha_j-1)}\ge \frac{\alpha_i\alpha_j-(\alpha_i+\alpha_j)+1}{(\alpha_i-1)(\alpha_j-1)}=1$$
with equality iff $\alpha_i=\alpha_j=\sqrt{\alpha_i\alpha_j}$.
Both inequalities together tell us that indeed $$\alpha_i=\alpha_j.$$
As this golds for all $i,j$, we conclude that $\alpha_k=\sqrt[n]{2145}$ for all $k$. This makes
$$f(1)=(\sqrt[n]{2145}-1)^n.$$
It is straightforward to verify that the right hand side is decreasing as a function of $n$, hence the maximum is achieved for $n=2$ and
$$ f(X)=(X-\sqrt{2145})^2$$
and the maximum is
$$ f(1)=(\sqrt{2145}-1)^2\approx 2053.37$$

Comment: Wow, thanks. What would be the maximum if n=4?

Comment: Hagen has given you the formula for $f(1)$, Jack, all you have to do is plug in the value of $n$. I'm sure you can do that.

Comment: Do you see that, Jack?

Comment: I do. Thank you.